# British hyphenation with either xelatex or lualatex

Tags: xetex, luatex, hyphenation, babel, polyglossia

For several reasons, I am working on a source file that should be compilable by either `xelatex` or `lualatex`. I would like British hyphenation for the text and am using `csquotes` and `biblatex` with `british` options.

On the XeTeX mailing list two things were mentioned:

(a) Use `polyglossia`, not `babel` with `xelatex`;

(b) `polyglossia` is incompatible with `lualatex` at present; use `babel` instead.

I show below a sample file with my question and my present setup.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
%
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Minion Pro}
    \setsansfont{Myriad Pro}
%
% We want to compile with either xelatex or lualatex
% The former requires polyglossia for british hyphenation
% The latter requires bable for british hyphenation
%
% Ideally something like (unsure if this is correct)
%
% \ifxetex
%       \usepackage{polyglossia}
%       \setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
%
% \ifluatex
%       usepackage[british]{babel}
%
% should work but I do not know the correct syntax for it.
%
% My workaround is:
%
\makeatletter
  \language=\l@british
\makeatother
%
% which works but is inelegant in a *LaTeX source file.
%   
\usepackage[backend=biber,babel=none,date=iso8601,urldate=iso8601,language=british,refsection=chapter,sorting=none,style=numeric-comp,hyperref=auto]{biblatex}
\usepackage[english=british]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
  Try some hyphenation, some \enquote{quotations}, and some references to see if everything works.
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions to make hyphenation and other language features like date work consistently across both `xelatex` and `lualatex` is most welcome.

Comment: Actually you *can* use **babel** with XeLaTeX, as long as you don't start trying it with exotic languages. English (both British and American) should work without any glitch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While **polyglossia** is widely recommended for XeLaTeX usage, **babel** can still be used for languages that need only the Latin alphabet.

Answer (score 8):

```
\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}
\ifxetex
       \usepackage{polyglossia}
       \setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\else\ifluatex
       \usepackage[british]{babel}
\fi\fi
```

This loads `polyglossia` for xetex and `babel` for luatex.

Comment: I find that the above works if I compile with `lualatex` and later with `xelatex`. However, if I first compile with `xelatex` and later with `lualatex` it gives me a `babel` error. I then need to delete the `.aux` file before compiling with `lualatex`, and all goes well. I point this out not because it is serious but because one needs to remember to delete the `.aux` file.

Comment: That's it! Indeed `.aux` files should be cleaned when you change compiler. I don't know remedy to copy with this problem.

Comment: @Igor it is due to the multi-pass nature of LaTeX. Thus, it is probably not to be solved, except for the deletion of temporary files. Which is probably a wise thing to do anyway when switching environment, as you mention.